# how to do count of particular value of given column corresponding to other column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

[image: input]

[image: output]

To count the particular value of given column

Answer (score 1):

Use [`pd.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) with [`df.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html):

```
In [236]: output = pd.crosstab(df['Rel_ID'], df['Values'])
In [238]: output['total'] = output.sum(axis=1)

In [239]: output
Out[239]: 
Values  400.0  500.0  1700.0  6300.0  total
Rel_ID                                     
TESTA       1      1       1       1      4
TESTB       1      0       1       1      3
TESTC       0      1       1       0      2
TESTD       1      0       1       1      3
TESTE       1      1       0       0      2
```